# Probability selecting $5$ cards from a standard $52$ card deck.

Tags: probability

Randomly select $5$ cards from a $52$ card deck. Let $A$ be the event that represents the outcomes that contain exactly $2$ queens where $1$ of them is the Queen of Hearts. Calculate $Pr(A)$.

What I have is $\frac{\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}48 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}52 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}}$.

Is this correct if not explain the right answer?

Comment: Picking the Queen of Hearts is $(1,1)$ not $(4,1)$. Otherwise seems good to me.

Answer (score 1):

No. of favorable outcomes $= 1 \times \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \times\begin{pmatrix} 48 \\ 3\end{pmatrix} = \frac{48 \times 47 \times 46}{2}$

Total no. of outcomes = $\begin{pmatrix} 52 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}=\frac{52 \times \dots \times 48}{5 \times \dots \times 2}$

Ans:- $P(A)=\frac{\frac{48 \times 47 \times 46}{2}}{\frac{52 \times \dots \times 48}{5 \times \dots \times 2}}= \frac{47 \times 46 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3}{52 \times  \dots \times 49}.$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same answer computed in a marginally different way.

The number of ways the cards can be, in order, $Q_\heartsuit Q_\overline{\heartsuit} \overline{Q} \,\overline{Q} \,\overline{Q}$
is $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46$.

These can be rearranged in ${5! \over 3!}$ ways and the total number of
ways we can select $5$ cards is $52 \cdots 48$.

Hence the chances are
${5! \over 3!}{ 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46 \over 52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48 } = { 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 47 \cdot 46\over 52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 }$.